# iOS simulator (iPhone6) viewControllers does not match storyBoard controllers

Tags: ios, iphone, layout, swift, storyboard

in another project of mine, which I started working on a few months ago, if I take some storyboard viewController and add it some pink view for instance, the pink view will appear exactly as in the storyboard when running in iOS simulator iPhone 6. while in a new project I'm working on, the view in iOS simulator (iPhone 6) is in size of the storyboard view (which is iPhone 5).
[image: iphone 5 view on iPhone 6 simulator]

btw, in my previous project i didn't use size Classes, and didn't have any constrains anywhere. I'd like it to stay like this in my current project. how can it be done ? 
thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to use constraints to get the views to resize automatically to fit the screen like that. AutoLayout is not that complicated, especially for something simple like this.

Comment: Well you need to use either Autolayout or set the correct autoresizing mask. The only other option is to layout everything in code.

Answer (score 1):

For the size issue as shown above, Check for the launch nib file. for the Project. use the launch file size to the maximum device size as for now 5.5'.

This could happen coz of any of 2 as below:

1. Try making launch file to 5.5inch size **OR** set Launchimage for
   big screen size.
2. Other than that Please check if you have set your view and its background to flexible width/height or not.

May be this could solve your issue.

Comment: can you please be more specific of how can I do it? I have a project working on iPhone 5 and the code is also suited to iPhone 5, how can I make it all suit to iPhone 6 without starting changing all the code??

Comment: please check for the launch xib file. and check for its screen size from fileinspector.

Comment: this pink color which is displaying is the background color or is that any image?